# Is the Skull Heart capable of having a male host?

Tags: skullgirls

The opening sequence goes something like this: "Every hundred years, the Skull Heart emerges to grant the wish of a pure-hearted girl. If, however, that girl's heart is impure, they will transform into the Skullgirl."

All fine and dandy...except now there is a male fighter in the roster - Big Band.

I haven't yet beaten the game as Big Band, but I've seen some playthroughs of the game on Youtube, and I know that most of the characters are offered a wish by the Skull Heart at the end...but I'm not sure about Big Band, since he's not exactly a 'girl'.

Does the Skull Heart offer this opportunity to Big Band, and thus affect men just as it affects women?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nope.

source: [canon lore thread](http://skullgirls.com/forums/index.php?threads/the-canon-info-thread-what-we-know.8/#post-43).

> Boys can't do much with the Skull Heart. They can look at it, punch it, yell at it, polish it, show it off as a trophy, turtle wax it.

Comment: I don't know how authoratative that thread is...but it looks official enough for me, a person who has no other source to base it on.